# why would didSelectRowAtIndexPath get called when tapping a selected cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a "select all" button that goes through and sets all the cells in a UITableView to selected.

When I then tap on a cell to unselect it, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets called, even though it is already selected. Therefore I have to tap it twice to make it unselected. The 2nd time I tap it, `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` gets called as expected.

When I tap the select all button, I reload the table view, and every cell that gets created in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets `cell.selected = YES`. So why would `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` get called when the cell is already in a selected state?

EDIT:
I have deduced that after I set `cell.selected = YES`, something called `UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath` is setting selected back to NO. Why is this happening?

Comment: @soeil was there ever a resolution to this issue? I'm encountering it upon trying to make my app compatible for iOS 15